# Hyperplane is isomorphic to the entire space in infinite dimension

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-space-isomorphism

Let be $E$ a vector space of infinite dimension.

I have the intuition that for all hyperplanes $F$ of $E$, there is an isomorphism between $F$ and $E$, it suffices to show this is true for an hyperplane and this will be true for all due to isomorphism between hyperplanes.

Then, I tried multiple things but I'm not allowed to use existence of basis in infinite dimension vector space or AC explicitly (or any equivalents statements).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** The trick is that we don't need a whole basis, it's enough to pick a countably infinite set of linearly independent vectors in $F$.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use such a set of vectors to build the isomorphism, I thought of it but there are vector space which have uncountably infinite set of linearly independent vectors in $E$ right? So moving from countably to uncountably is not possible right?

Comment: I was thinking that we might get a complementary subspace to $span(a, e_1,e_w,\dots)$ and define our map as the identity there. However, I'm now uncertain about the existence of such complementary subspace without AC..

Comment: Indeed, such a complementary set won't exist without AC I believe...